# List Biggest_Purchase In Desc Order In Group By Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

The following is my query:

```
select MAX(o.amount)as Biggest_Purchase , c.cust_fname, c.cust_lname 
from orders o, customer c
where o.cust_num = c.cust_num
group by c.cust_fname, c.cust_lname
order by o.amount desc;
```

Why am I getting the following error?:

Msg 8127, Level 16, State 1, Line 5
Column "orders.amount" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only specify columns in the `select` clause in an `order by`.  I think you mean:

```
select MAX(o.amount)as Biggest_Purchase , c.cust_fname, c.cust_lname 
from orders o, customer c
where o.cust_num = c.cust_num
group by c.cust_fname, c.cust_lname
order by Biggest_Purchase desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select MAX(o.amount)as Biggest_Purchase , c.cust_fname, c.cust_lname 
from orders o, customer c
where o.cust_num = c.cust_num
group by c.cust_fname, c.cust_lname
order by max(o.amount) desc;
```